# Удаление символов из строки до определенного

Tags: java

Есть такая строка:

```
�ifatrack.wktlinestring(321231, 321312, 3231)
```

Как получить значение:

```
321231, 321312, 3231
```

Пробовал через регулярки, на подобие такого:

```
"/Date(1245398693390)/".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

а также через приведение типов к `char` и поиску посимвольно. Не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `String` есть метод `lastIndexOf`:

```
String test = "�track.wktlinestring(321231, 321312, 3231)";

int bracket = test.lastIndexOf("(");

System.out.println(test.substring(bracket));

// (321231, 321312, 3231)
```

Comment: Я пробовал через IndexOf похоже где то напортачил, спасибо)

Comment: Скобки я убрал через регулярку (вдруг кому понадобится):
`System.out.println(test.substring(bracket).replaceAll("^\\(|\\)$", ""));`